# What is the fastest way to delete all customers from SQL Server based on that customer not meeting a single criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let me explain by way of example. Consider the following table:

```
Customer Id | Food
------------+---------
1           | Pizza       
1           | Burger   
1           | Hot Dog  
2           | Milkshake       
2           | Burger   
3           | Pizza
```

I want to delete all the records for customers who have **NEVER** ordered Pizza. So, I should be left with this (customer #2 deleted):

```
Customer Id | Food
------------+---------
1           | Pizza       
1           | Burger   
1           | Hot Dog  
3           | Pizza
```

I know I can do a `NOT IN` but the performance is horrible.

**What is the most performant way to write this query to achieve this against 100,000+ records in SQL Server?**

Comment: It would be useful if you gave the query you tried. Have you tried [`NOT EXISTS`](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/) as well?

Comment: IF the NOT EXISTS version is still not quick enough for you, try using `DELETE TOP (x) FROM Table WHERE NOT EXISTS ....` where x is a batch size. Say 10,000.  This will let you break your delete up into batches and reduce the transaction size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple `NOT EXISTS` should be [efficient](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) with proper indexes.

```
DELETE c1 FROM Customers c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Customers  c2
    WHERE c1.[Customer Id] = c2.[Customer Id]
    AND c2.[Food] = 'Pizza'
);
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d30c6/5/1)

Create an index on `[Customer Id]` and a non-clustered index on `Food`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The link to http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join was very useful.

Answer (score 4):

how about `NOT EXISTS`

```
DELETE  a
FROM    table1 a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    table1 b
            WHERE   a.customerID = b.customerID AND
                    b.Food = 'Pizza'
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81d18/1)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
delete t from t 
left join (select distinct [Customer Id] from t where Food='Pizza') t2
on t.[Customer Id]=t2.[Customer Id]
where t2.[Customer Id] is null
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/994b9/1)

Comment: [This `LEFT OUTER JOIN` pattern consistently performs worst out of the various options](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Answer (score 0):

- If the table size is huge, try deleting in batches. 
  or
- Move the records which needs not to be deleted in a temporary table.Truncate the main table and then move the rest of the records from the temporary table to the main table.